# Windows batch allow numbers and blank only input for variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have the following line of code:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=0123456789" %%a in ("A0%att:"=%") do if not "%%b"=="" echo Only numbers, no spaces or letters! && goto next
```

It works great, however, if there is no input, the batch crashes. Is there any adjustment to incl. or excl. a 'non entry'?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess this is because of the unbalanced quotes in `A0%att:"=%`; perhaps assign the `%att:"=%` to an interim variable first...

Comment: SET /P command sets errorlevel to 1 in case of no input. However, you could preset the att variable to some undesired string e.g. SET "att=X"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the super late reply, but I think I found a workaround to exclude empty input:

```
@echo off
set /p "att="

if "%att%"=="" goto :invalid

for /f "tokens=1* delims=0123456789" %%a in ("A0%att:"=%") do (
    if not "%%b"=="" goto :invalid
)

echo It is a number
pause
    goto :next

:invalid
echo Only numbers, no spaces or letters!
pause
    goto :next
```

The script above does:

- Get input
- Check if input is empty, if true, `goto :invalid`
- Use the `for` loop you provided to check if `%att%` is a number